# Change ID to same ID if other value is same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help to write a query

```
**ID DOB**
1   1/1/2000
2   1/1/2000
3   2/2/1999
4   2/2/1999
```

If DOB is the same make ID the lowest value

so an example of the results are

```
1   1/1/2000
1   1/1/2000
3   2/2/1999
3   2/2/1999
```

notice the IDs are now the same

if i haven't explained it well enough please ask me any questions

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the ANSI SQL window function `min()`:

```
select min(id) over (partition by dob) as id, dob
from t;
```

EDIT:

I'm not quite sure why you would want to set rows to be exact duplicates, but you can do that in a similar way:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, min(id) over (partition by dob) as new_id
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set id = new_id
    where id <> new_id;
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, if i want to actually change the Data in the DB how would i do that

Comment: when i tried this it won't know what new_id is in the where id <> new_id

Comment: @BobLaw . . . It should.  Both columns are in `toupdate`.